# How can I set up a second router for my roommate to improve his signal strength/coverage, and so that he is on a different subnet from mine?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

My situation is as follows - I have a Wi-Fi router that covers one corner of the house with SSID call it `PRIMARY_SSID`, but does not reach the other corner where my roommate is.  I've read about how I could use a second Wi-Fi router in Bridge mode (turn off DHCP) and set it on a different frequency channel so that my roommate can have strong connection to our Internet.

However, he will be plugging his devices into that router and I want him to be on a different subnet so that he cannot access my devices.  How?

In short, I am trying to solve two problems;

1. Improve signal strength for my roommate
2. Have my roommate be on a different subnet from mine.  Also, can I keep the same SSID for him or will it have to be a different one, i.e. `SECONDARY_SSID`?

My experience with routers is I have used only one router before, but I am not sure how to go about setting up this particular situation.  I imagine I cannot use Bridge mode, and I might need to set up specific subnets on both routers.  How and what do I enter?  With respect to SSID even if the same SSID is possible, it may be better to set up a different name for him so that he knows it's his SSID to connect to.  How do I connect these routers? - Can I use ethernet cable from first router's port to second router's port? Which ports?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem.

If its possible to do so, the easiest way would be to get a second router.   Move and reconfigure the current router to serve your flatmate.   Connect the WAN port of your new router to the LAN port of his router over ethernet.   Have separate SSID's for the 2 devices, and reconfigure your router to use a different subnet to his (ie if the current router uses 192.168.1.x use 10.0.0.x on yours).  This will isolate your network from his (but not his network from yours, as your router becomes a client of his).

If this is not possible, you can reverse the above, ie keep your router as is, and connect the WAN port of a router for your Roommate to your routers LAN port.  You again need separate SSID's and networks.   In order to prevent your roommate accessing your router you will need to add a firewall rule ON YOUR ROOMATES ROUTER to prevent it routing traffic for your LAN onto yours (save for the common router IP)

An alternative to 2 routers with rules on the client router would be to have an ethernet router feeding each of 2 WIFI routers - even using standard NAT under this scenario will fix the ability to hop between networks.  This is likely the "fairest" way of doing things, assuming you are each paying 50% for the resources.  Also ethernet only routers are cheap.   The disadvantage is both parties have double NAT.   You will still need seperate SSID's

ALL OF THE ABOVE SOLUTIONS assume you can connect the 2 routers using ethernet (or look at Ethernet over powerline to link them)

Connecting the 2 connections over WIFI is harder and more wasteful -

A more expensive approach would be to use routers and bridges where 1 router supports multiple SSID's, and the SSID's can be configured to be independent.  Ubiquity (no doubt among others) provides this - but this is harder to set up (you will need to understand about VLANS etc)

**If you require fairly strong separation between the networks and don't want to become an expert in networking, you will want to have separate SSID's.**  Using prosumer/professional grade (again, Ubiquity can do this), you can have a single SSID and drop the customer into an appropriate VLAN network based on their credentials.